# What's the right way to navigate through xml file using java dom?

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I have an xml file like below:

```
<mon:eventPointData>
<mon:kind mon:version="2010-11-11">bpmnx:EVENT_CAUGHT</mon:kind>
<mon:time mon:of="occurrence">2016-11-29T14:31:47.365-02:00</mon:time>
<mon:model mon:type="wle:processApplication">
  <mon:name>DEF Application</mon:name>
  <mon:documentation/>
  <wle:snapshot-name>Version 1</wle:snapshot-name>
</mon:model>
<mon:model mon:type="bpmn:startEvent">
  <mon:name>Start</mon:name>
  <mon:instance mon:id="2"/>
  <wle:snapshot-name>Version 1</wle:snapshot-name>
</mon:model>
<mon:model mon:type="bpmn:process" >
  <mon:name>DEF Test</mon:name>
  <mon:documentation/>
  <mon:instance mon:id="253">
    <mon:state>Active</mon:state>
  </mon:instance>
  <wle:snapshot-name>Version 1</wle:snapshot-name>
</mon:model>
```

To navigate and get values of tags and attributes I'm using java dom, but to get each value I think I'm doing a lot of effort, so I think I'm doing it in the wrong way.

To get mon:kind value I'm using

```
String kind = doc.getElementsByTagName("mon:kind").item(0).getTextContent();
```

To get "name" inside "model" where attribute "mon:type" is equals to "wle:processApplication", I'm doing the following:

```
for (int x = 0; x < e.getElementsByTagName("mon:model").getLength(); x++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.getElementsByTagName("mon:model").item(0).getAttributes().getLength(); i++) {
            if (e.getElementsByTagName("mon:model").item(0).getAttributes().item(i).getNodeValue()
                    .equals("bpmn:process")) {
                String name = ((Element)e.getElementsByTagName("mon:model").item(0)).getElementsByTagName("mon:name").item(0).getTextContent();

            }
        }
}
```

It works, but I'm confortable with this solution. Am I doing it in the right way?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, DOM walking can get messy. You might want to look into a framework that does much of this sort of thing for you such as JAXB - you can map XML documents directly onto POJOs without having to write lots of tree walking code like this. What you have will probably be a bit faster though...

Comment: have you tried xpath?

Comment: @the8472 didn't. But now I'll.